# How to make the taskbar appears on top of a full screen application automatically?

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config, taskbar, google-chrome

Do I need to show the taskbar on top of a full-screen page opened by google chrome browser?
Is it possible?

I tried to search but no results were found.

Thanks.

Comment: That defeats the definition of *full screen*. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jacobm001 i'm creating a website that should be started after the booting automatically, the thing is that the raspberry pi needs to connect to the wifi before. that's why i need the internet icon to be shown on top of the browser. The only way to control the website is by voice command using speech API. i cant control the raspberry pi by voice. the only way is to attach mouse in the raspberry. but i need the icon to be shown first, i don't want the user to minimize the website and go for the network

Comment: Why not set it to automatically connect?

Comment: i'm doing this project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkVBAcvbrjU and i want to give the user the ability to connect to any network. in the same time i don't want the user to leave the website that resides on the raspberry pi. Is there a way to make the user to connect to any network through the browser? OR is there a way to make the taskbar appear on the top? @Jacobm001

Answer (score 1):

The chromium-browser layer and the problem I was having where the taskbar didn't pop up from below because the windows covered it. I just edited the openbox config file (see source on how)

```
<application name="panel" type="dock">
<layer>below</layer>
</application>
```

to:

```
<application name="panel" type="dock">
<layer>above</layer>
</application>
```

---

Source:
[Graphical layers configuration do not stick after reboot](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=264475&p=1608654#p1608654)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `Alt+F11` if on windows keyboard connected directly or remotely to the Raspberry Pi. If using Mac to connect remotely (via VNC or similar remote control), try `Opt + F11` or `Fn + Opt + F11`.

This combination toggle full-screen mode on or off and will therefore make the browser window that is hiding the taskbar become a normal window again and show the taskbar.

The above assumes i understand your question correctly, meaning on startup of the RPi, a browser window set to ran at startup is coming up in full screen mode and does have window control (to close it) and in addition, is hiding the taskbar and withit the RPi menu.